# How can I get Promise return object from asynchronous function in another module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a module containing my method to fetch data asynchronously using axios.

services.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
class Services {

static callAPI(params) {
    var headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    axios({
        method:'get',
        url: params.url,
        headers: headers
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response;
    });
}}export { Services }
```

I am importing this module into my component module A.js

A.js

```
class Modules extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
    this.getData().then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}

getData(){
    var prom = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       resolve(Services.callAPI({url: Paths.localAPIPath() + '/module',accept: 'application/json'}));
    });
    return prom;
}

render() {
    return (
        <p></p>
    )
}}export default Modules
```

I see my Asynchronous method call inside the network tab, but cannot console the response, am I doing it all wrong or what??

Get undefined inside the console, that means either data is missing or the call to console.log is synchronous.

So to sum up all of this
**How to asynchronously get data from another asynchronous function inside another module file using native promise method.**

Comment: `callAPI` doesn't return anything. It should be `return axios...` and simply `getData() { return Services.callAPI(...); }`.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format the code with consistent, reasonably standard indentation and line breaks, to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: go through $q in angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `callAPI` method so that it actually returns something (and get rid of the `then` that serves no purpose):

```
static callAPI(params) {
    var headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    return axios({
        method:'get',
        url: params.url,
        headers: headers
    })
}
```

Change your `getData` method so that it returns the value of `callAPI` (everything else you have in that method is useless):

```
getData(){
    return Services.callAPI({
        url: Paths.localAPIPath() + '/module',
        accept: 'application/json'
    });
}
```

That should do it.